# How to merge multiple consecutive values in a list?

Tags: c#, list, distinct

Is there a function to remove consequent values (i.e. `14, 14 -> 14`, `12, 12 -> 12`)?

The following list (`[12, 14, 14, 12, 12, 14]`):

```
List<string> foo = new List<string> { 12, 14, 14, 12, 12, 14 };
```

to the list `[12, 14, 12, 14]`?

Comment: Surely this has been asked before.

Comment: @Micha Probably you are right, but could't find it with my own words.

Comment: You could iterate through the list, and keep track of the last seen element. If the last seen element matches the current element, continue, else update the last seen element to the current value and yield the current value to be further used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Linq* without additional libraries, but with *side effects* is a *quick and dirty* (`prior` side effect is ugly) solution:

```
  List<string> foo = new List<string> { "12", "14", "14", "12", "12", "14" };

  string prior = null;

  List<string> result = foo
    .Where((v, i) => i == 0 || v != prior)
    .Select(v => prior = v)
    .ToList();
```

In *general case*, you may want to implement an *extension method*:

```
  public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {  
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctSuccessive<T>(
      this IEnumerable<T> source, 
           IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) {
      // public method arguments validation
      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

      // equals: either default or custom one 
      Func<T, T, bool> equals = (left, right) => null == comparer 
        ? object.Equals(left, right) 
        : comparer.Equals(left, right);

      bool first = true;
      T prior = default(T);

      foreach (var item in source) {
        if (first || !equals(item, prior))
          yield return item;

        first = false;
        prior = item;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then

```
  List<string> result = foo
    .DistinctSuccessive()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Approach with `foreach`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctByPrevious<T>(List<T> source)
{
    if (source != null && source.Any())
    {
        T prev = source.First();
        yield return prev;
        foreach (T item in source.Skip(1))
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, prev))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
            prev = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but in *general case*, if `IEnumerable<T>` is not a *materialized collection*, but, say, a file - `File.ReadLines("c:\myFile.txt")` you can have *incosistent* results of `source.Any()` - first materialization; `source.First()` - second materialization and `foreach(...source.Skip(1))` - third one.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Can you please point me at the relevant part of the specification (if three is such a thing). I'd like to understand in more detail why there might be a problem, and ideally based on a specification.

Comment: @Micha Wiedenmann: imagine that `source` is a *file* e.g. `File.ReadLines("c:\MyFile.csv")`. Then `source.Any()` will open the file and try to read the 1st line it'll return `true` if the first line exists. Next we call `source.First()`, but file can have been *changed* (e.g. cleared) and now we have an exception thrown `First()` on empty sequence

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I've changed my answer to `List<T>` to avoid this special case - SQLDataReader has the same problem

Comment: Based on this level of rigorosity, not even List<T> is fine, since it can also be altered in parallel. In fact apart from arrays and immutable types I don't see any chance of using LINQ while satisfying this constraint. – Micha Wiedenmann 35 mins ago

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefere @fubo answer, but just to show that there is more variants:

```
var data = new[] { 12, 14, 14, 12, 12, 14 };
var result = data.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (a, e) => { if (a.FirstOrDefault() != e) a.Insert(0, e); return a; });
result.Reverse(); // we builded a list in a back order, so reverse it!
```

Comment: Very inefficient, because of the `LastOrDefault` call.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, true. Can be good only for short lists. I should edit my answer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias how about this? :)

Comment: ＠vasily.sib vastly superior. :-)